# Laravel: How can the database be checked for whether it contains a particular value?

Tags: mysql, laravel, middleware

Laravel: How can the database be checked for whether it contains a particular value?

How can a mysql query that does the following be done with a Laravel call from within a middleware?

```
let $query = 'SELECT * FROM misctable WHERE miscfield  = ?';

        var result = connection.query(
        $query,[ miscvariable ], 
        function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err){
            console.log("An error occurred performing the query.");
            return;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a model for the table you can use the DB facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$results = DB::table('misctable')->where('miscfield', $miscvariable);
```

Comment: Adding `->get();` at the end was required to get it working.  Thanks!